# rpc requests to geth on AWS instance

Tags: go-ethereum, aws, rpc

I have geth running on an AWS EC2 instance. Here is how I started it:

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8545"  --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

from that same instance I can use python's `request.post` to issue a RPC request to `http://localhost:8545`. It works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to do the same request from my local computer by requesting to `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8545` but Im getting the error bellow:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='xx.xxx.xxx.xx', port=8545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000028F39163438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

I have added rules on AWS security group to allow all inboud from all IPs.
what could I be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to AWS instance via RPC you have to assign the public IP of that instance as the rpc address.

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "Public IP of AWS" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

If it was behind any proxy server then you have to redirect the request from a proxy server to your AWS server through port forwarding.